# SharePoint Search: How to tell SharePoint to NOT send me its managed properties in the result set?

Tags: 2013, search, rest, 2016, search-api

I'm calling the SharePoint Search REST API like this, saying I want only the value of managed property **SomeProperty**:

`https://sharepoint/_api/search/query?querytext='trololo'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='SomeProperty'`

What SharePoint gives me:

- SomeProperty
- *Rank*
- *DocId*
- *PartitionId*
- *AAMEnabledManagedProperties*
- *RenderTemplateId*

How can I tell SharePoint to not send me these *other properties*, as I don't need them and they bloat the result by an outrageous amount?